# getting Woocommerce order number into Gravity Perks Nested Form

Tags: php, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Woocommerce + Gravity forms with the WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons.  My form contains a Nested Gravity Perks Form.  I need to add the Woocommerce Order number to both the parent and the child gravity form.  I have accomplished this with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wc_add_order_id' );<br>function wc_add_order_id( $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];  
        if ( has_term( 'camp', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //my woocommerce category
            $meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data();
            $meta_data_items = $item->get_meta_data();
            foreach ( $meta_data_items as $meta ) {
                $entry_id = $meta->value['_gravity_form_linked_entry_id'];
                $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
                $entry['40'] = $order_id ;  //40 is the id of a single field reserved for the Order #
                $result = GFAPI::update_entry( $entry );
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I then tried the following to add the order number to my child form (this works if I manually update the parent form entry.  It does not work automatically from the update_entry trigger above:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_update_entry_82', function ( $form, $entry_id ) { //82 is the parent form id<br>
    $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
    $entry_child_order = rgar( $entry, '2' );  //2 is the field that contains the entry id of the child
    $order_id = rgar( $entry, '40' ); //this has the Woocommerce Order #
    $entry2 = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_child_order); 
    $entry2['147'] = $order_id ; //147 is the single field reserved for the order number
    $result = GFAPI::update_entry( $entry2 );
    return $result;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Does anyone know why "GFAPI::update_entry( $entry );" doesn't automatically trigger the second half of this code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out. I was able to put everything into the same function and it is working.

```
//add order number to gravity forms
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wc_add_order_id' );
function wc_add_order_id( $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$cart_reg = $order->get_items();
$entry_id = array();
$entry_id2 = array();
$entry_id[] = $linked_entry;
$entry_id2[] = $linked_nested_value;
foreach( $cart_reg as $key => $value) {  
    $linked_entry=$value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"];
    $entry_id = $linked_entry;
    $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
    $entry['40'] = $order_id;  //40 is my field number that will contain orede number
    $result = GFAPI::update_entry( $entry );
    $linked_nested_value=$value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_lead"]['2'];
    if(!$linked_nested_value == ''){
        $nested_value_array = preg_split ("/\,/", $linked_nested_value); //array of child entries
        $child_entry_amt = substr_count($linked_nested_value, ",") + 1;
    }//child entries

    if ($child_entry_amt > 0){   
        for ($n = 0; $n < $child_entry_amt; $n++) {
            $entry_id2=$nested_value_array[$n];
            $entry2 = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id2 );
            $entry2['147'] = $order_id;//this is my field number on my child form that will contain order number
            $result2 = GFAPI::update_entry( $entry2 );
        }
    }
}
```

};